# How does Kendo grid convert the object reference list in the parent row's columns into new row below the parent row?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, .net-6.0

I have a data grid below, how can I made kendo grid display like this?

| [ ] | num | month | Start | end | week | num | start | end | hour | Lock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [x] | 7 | July | 07/05 | 07/05 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  | week 1 | 1 | 07/05 | 07/05 | 40 | Yes |
|  |  |  |  |  | week 2 | 2 | 07/05 | 07/05 | 40 | No |
|  |  |  |  |  | week 3 | 3 | 07/05 | 07/05 | 40 | NO |
|  |  |  |  |  | week 4 | 4 | 07/05 | 07/05 | 40 | Yes |
| [x] | 8 | August | 08/07 | 08/05 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  | week 1 | 1 | 08/05 | 08/05 | 40 | Yes |
|  |  |  |  |  | week 2 | 2 | 08/05 | 08/05 | 40 | No |
|  |  |  |  |  | week 3 | 3 | 08/05 | 08/05 | 40 | Yes |
|  |  |  |  |  | week 4 | 4 | 08/05 | 08/05 | 40 | Yes |
| [x] | 9 | September | 09/05 | 09/05 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  | week 1 | 1 | 09/05 | 09/05 | 40 | Yes |
|  |  |  |  |  | week 2 | 2 | 09/05 | 09/05 | 40 | No |
|  |  |  |  |  | week 3 | 3 | 09/05 | 09/05 | 40 | Yes |
|  |  |  |  |  | week 4 | 4 | 09/05 | 09/05 | 40 | No |

I created 2 model with one-to-many ralationship

Month.cs

```
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public int num { get; set; }
 public string month{ get; set;}
 public DateTime Start { get; set; }
 public DateTime End { get; set; }
 public List<Week> Weeks{ get; set; }
```

Week.cs

```
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public int num{ get; set; }
 public string week { get; set;}
 public DateTime Start { get; set; }
 public DateTime End { get; set; }
 public int hours { get; set; }
 public Boolean Lock { get; set; }
 public int MonthId { get; set; }
 public Month Months { get; set; }
```

I can only make the kendo grid show one of the 2 models above like this

Month.cs

| [ ] | num | month | Start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [x] | 7 | July | 07/05 | 07/05 |
| [x] | 8 | August | 08/05 | 08/05 |
| [x] | 9 | September | 09/05 | 0/05 |

Week.cs

| [ ] | week | num | start | end | hour | Lock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [x] | week 1 | 1 | 07/05 | 09/05 | 40 | Yes |
| [x] | week 2 | 2 | 07/05 | 09/05 | 40 | No |
| [x] | week 3 | 3 | 07/05 | 09/05 | 40 | Yes |
| [x] | week 4 | 4 | 07/05 | 09/05 | 40 | No |
| [x] | week 1 | 1 | 08/05 | 09/05 | 40 | Yes |
| [x] | week 2 | 2 | 08/05 | 09/05 | 40 | No |
| [x] | week 3 | 3 | 08/05 | 09/05 | 40 | Yes |
| [x] | week 4 | 4 | 08/05 | 09/05 | 40 | No |
| [x] | week 1 | 1 | 09/05 | 09/05 | 40 | Yes |
| [x] | week 2 | 2 | 09/05 | 09/05 | 40 | No |
| [x] | week 3 | 3 | 09/05 | 09/05 | 40 | Yes |
| [x] | week 4 | 4 | 09/05 | 09/05 | 40 | No |

If I use ViewModel with both properties from Month.cs and Week.cs then kendo grid like this

| [ ] | num | month | Start | end | week | num | start | end | hour | Lock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [x] | 7 | July | 07/05 | 07/05 | week 1 | 1 | 07/05 | 07/05 | 40 | Yes |
| [x] | 8 | August | 08/07 | 08/05 | week 1 | 1 | 08/05 | 08/05 | 40 | Yes |
| [x] | 9 | September | 09/05 | 09/05 | week 1 | 1 | 09/05 | 09/05 | 40 | Yes |

Comment: What have you tried or where are you stuck at? You're asking for a full solution from query to grid rendering. There is a lot of stuff to do to acheive that. I mean, if youre stuck in the linq query, open a question with linq tag.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown I just add more detail for my questtion

Comment: Why won't you use expand/collapse feature ? https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/detailtemplate